# TFS 2010 - The path E:\SSIS is already mapped in workspace PC-mypc01

Tags: tfs

I have a number of SSIS packages spread throughout TFS, e.g. `\Imports\impSSIS01\\`, `\OtherPackages\Exports\expSSIS02\\`, etc.  Anytime I open up any of those, I want the working directory to be `E:\SSIS\`, e.g. `E:\SSIS\impSSIS01\\*.\*`, `E:\SSIS\expSSIS01\\*.\*`  When I try to set up my workspaces like that though, I get the error:

> The path `E:\SSIS` is already mapped in workspace `PC-MYCP01`

I don't care if it's already mapped.  I know it's already mapped.  I **want** it to be already mapped.  Just let me map it.

(Also, does this mean no one else on my team could use `E:\SSIS\`?  I hope not, it's a shared drive we all need to use.)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried removing all your mappings and then map the root of your Tfs collection to e:\ssis.   That way getting latest on a sub folder will extract the contents to a folder relative to e:\ssis.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response.  

I'm not sure I understand.  If in TFS it *\Folder1\F2\F3\MySSIS1\* I want the working directory to be *E:\SSIS\MySSIS1\*.  

If something's in TFS as *\Folder1\F4\MySSIS_2\*, I want it to be in *E:\SSIS\MySSIS_2\*.

Comment: If they all had a common parent folder it would be easy, just map the parent.  In your case you have to map each one separately.  So remove mapping to e:\ssis from your workspace.  Go to each *\ssis1 and set the mapping to e:\ssis\ssis1

Comment: A folder can only be mapped in one workspace at a time.  You can find workspaces in VS under File -> Source Control -> Workspaces.  Select one and click Edit.  You'll see the mappings here and A) delete the workspace, B) delete the mapping, C) change the mapping, D) something I haven't thought of yet

Answer (score 1):

Download the free **[Team Foundation Sidekicks 2010](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)**. It provides a convenient way to delete and modify workspaces.